# React-native how to move up Textfield above keyboard

Tags: node.js, react-native, keyboard, scrollview

I am trying to move textfields up while showing the keyboard.
I am doing login screen in react native application, So, I have added `Scrollview`.

But, Its scrolling for all devices. But, I need only for iPhone 5s device only.

Even I tried with `KeyboardAvoidingView`, But, due to this entire data is overlapping.

Any suggestions to avoid this issue?

Comment: If you have knowledge of integrating native library then you can use this https://github.com/douglasjunior/react-native-keyboard-manager it automatically handles scrolling content up from your keyboard on IOS and on android  you can put this (android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize") on your activity tag on manifest.

Comment: I installed and after import I tried to use it   componentDidMount() {
    KeyboardManager.setEnable(true);
    KeyboardManager.setToolbarPreviousNextButtonEnable(true);
  }
//but showing error like setEnable undefined.

Comment: just installing wont do. you have to link it with your react native project because it's a native library here is link that show's how it's done. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Comment: I have linked it already

Comment: They just told install and link. That's it

Comment: some times link command does not work so what you do is manually link it my above link show you how to do that all you need to do is go to node_modules folder then in folder says react-native-keyboard-manager grab that project and drag it to your project.

Comment: Ok. Will follow that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still looking:
There are 2 libraries that help to get the best result with that, for any input field on the content.

1. 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview';
2. 'react-native-keyboard-tracking-view';

just import the following:

```
   import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview';
   import {KeyboardAwareInsetsView} from 'react-native-keyboard-tracking-view';
```

and your render method should be like:

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
       <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <KeyboardAwareScrollView style={{flex: 1}} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}>
          {this.renderInputContent()}
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        {this.renderCTA()}
        <KeyboardAwareInsetsView/>
       <View/>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use KeyboardAvoidingView but not with scrollview because scrollview does not have a height. If you have to use KeyboardAvoidingView use without scroll view and if u are using scrollview then automatically u can scroll up and see the text field

Comment: KeyboardAvoidingView If I use this, The bottom text is overlapping in Login screen.

Comment: post a screenshot

Comment: also be careful where to put KeyboardAvoidingView.. Put it below the view of textfield

Comment: I have added like this <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }} behavior="padding" enabled>
<TextInput>
</TextInput>
<TextInput>
</TextInput>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>

Comment: <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled> . Try this. just above the textfield

Comment: Its moved completely top to screen, not even showing complete layout. Not working, New issues came.

Comment: Yaa as I said, you have to be careful using them.. You have to puth keyboard avoiding view in corresponding views so that it gets proper height